# how to use javacv in android for mouth detection?

Tags: android, javacv

hi I am currently working on mouth detection in android,
 but the every time that I will run my work it crushes always, please help me

```
package com.example.chuba;

import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvClearMemStorage;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvLoad;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.cvLoadImage;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect.CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect.cvHaarDetectObjects;

import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvMemStorage;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvSeq;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect.CvHaarClassifierCascade;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        open();

    }
public void open(){
    TextView v = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detect);

    final String XML_FILE = 
            "C://Users//Michelle//adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702//Chuba//src//com//example//chuba//haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml";
    IplImage img = cvLoadImage("C://Users//Michelle//adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702//Chuba//src//com//example//chuba//michelle.jpg");      
    try{



        CvHaarClassifierCascade cascade = new 
                CvHaarClassifierCascade(cvLoad(XML_FILE));
        CvMemStorage storage = CvMemStorage.create();
        CvSeq sign = cvHaarDetectObjects(
            img,
                cascade,
                storage,
                1.5,
                25,
                CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING);

        cvClearMemStorage(storage);

        int total_Faces = sign.total(); 


        v.setText(total_Faces+"");
        }catch(Exception e){
            v.setText("sorry failed");  
        }
}
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and here are the errors came from the eclipse console

```
[2014-07-31 17:08:04 - Chuba] Android Launch!
[2014-07-31 17:08:04 - Chuba] adb is running normally.
[2014-07-31 17:08:04 - Chuba] Performing com.example.chuba.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-07-31 17:08:04 - Chuba] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device       compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2014-07-31 17:08:05 - Chuba] Installing Chuba.apk...
[2014-07-31 17:08:08 - Chuba] Uploading Chuba.apk onto device '0123456789ABCDEF'
[2014-07-31 17:08:15 - Chuba] Success!
[2014-07-31 17:08:15 - Chuba] Starting activity com.example.chuba.MainActivity on device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2014-07-31 17:08:16 - Chuba] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.chuba/.MainActivity }
[2014-07-31 17:08:19 - Chuba] Installing Chuba.apk...
[2014-07-31 17:08:25 - Chuba] Installation failed due to invalid URI!
[2014-07-31 17:08:25 - Chuba] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-07-31 17:08:25 - Chuba] Launch canceled!
```

please help me please

Comment: `[2014-07-31 17:08:25 - Chuba] Please check logcat output for more details.` -- have you checked logcat output? Add those related messages to your question.

Comment: cant find higui java something like that

Comment: ive follow everything on how to set up the javacv in android http://blog.drndos.sk/2013/04/how-to-run-javacv-with-sample-face-recognition-on-android-arm-device-netbeans-and-nbandroid/ in this link

Answer (score 0):

This error can point to so many different things, and there is many different fixes. To sum those I've gathered:

*Problems with Eclipse: Clean project, rebuild project, restart eclipse.*

1. Invalid characters: Remove any special characters in Eclipse project name. Use only [a-z] and [0-9] not even [ ] (whitespace)
2. Error in included jar: Try without jar and see if it runs, if does fix somehow.
3. Errors in manifest package setup: Right click in eclipse on project -> Android tools -> Rename application package (rename to something similar, you can always rename back).
4. Problems with device: Remove app from device and try re install.
5. Rom issue: If you use custom ROM try to reflash to a new ROM.
6. Debugging not enabled: On phone go to Settings -> Applications -> Allow unknown sources/enable debugging (this path can vary for different devices)